# parallel::mclapply() adds or removes bindings to the global environment. Which ones?

Tags: r, mclapply

## Why this matters

For [`drake`](https://github.com/ropensci/drake), I want users to be able to execute `mclapply()` calls within a locked global environment. The environment is locked for the sake of reproducibility. [Without locking, data analysis pipelines could invalidate themselves](https://github.com/ropensci/drake/issues/664#issuecomment-453163562).

## Evidence that `mclapply()` adds or removes global bindings

```r
set.seed(0)
a <- 1

# Works as expected.
rnorm(1)
#> [1] 1.262954
tmp <- parallel::mclapply(1:2, identity, mc.cores = 2)

# No new bindings allowed.
lockEnvironment(globalenv())

# With a locked environment
a <- 2 # Existing bindings are not locked.
b <- 2 # As expected, we cannot create new bindings.
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): cannot add bindings to a locked environment
tmp <- parallel::mclapply(1:2, identity, mc.cores = 2) # Unexpected error.
#> Warning in parallel::mclapply(1:2, identity, mc.cores = 2): all scheduled
#> cores encountered errors in user code
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

### EDIT

For the original motivating problem, see https://github.com/ropensci/drake/issues/675 and https://ropenscilabs.github.io/drake-manual/hpc.html#parallel-computing-within-targets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the `.Random.seed` yourself before you lock the environment. Also you need to load the library (or use the function before) and assign `tmp` to something.

```
library(parallel)
tmp <- NULL
rm(".Random.seed", envir = .GlobalEnv, inherits = FALSE)
lockEnvironment(globalenv())
tmp <- parallel::mclapply(1:2, identity, mc.cores = 2)
```

Of course this will not allow functions that need `.Random.seed` like `rnorm` to work.

A workaround is to to change the RNG kind to "L'Ecuyer-CMRG", see also here `?nextRNGStream`:

```
library(parallel)
tmp <- NULL
RNGkind("L'Ecuyer-CMRG")
lockEnvironment(globalenv())
tmp <- parallel::mclapply(1:2, rnorm, mc.cores = 2)
```

**EDIT**

I thought of another solution to your problem and I think this will work with any RNG (did not test much). You can override the function that removes `.Random.seed` with one that just sets it to `NULL`

```
library(parallel)
mc.set.stream <- function () {
  if (RNGkind()[1L] == "L'Ecuyer-CMRG") {
    assign(".Random.seed", get("LEcuyer.seed", envir = RNGenv), 
           envir = .GlobalEnv)
  } else {
    if (exists(".Random.seed", envir = .GlobalEnv, inherits = FALSE)) {
      assign(".Random.seed", NULL, envir = .GlobalEnv)
    }  
  }
}

assignInNamespace("mc.set.stream", mc.set.stream, asNamespace("parallel"))
tmp <- NULL
set.seed(0)
lockEnvironment(globalenv())
tmp <- parallel::mclapply(1:2, rnorm, mc.cores = 2)
```

One final thought: you can create a new environment containing all things you don't want to be changed, lock it and work in there.

Comment: Good ideas. Unfortunately, these approaches do not fit my use case. [`drake`](https://github.com/ropensci/drake) is designed for reproducible pseudo-randomness. It sets `.Random.seed` on its own, so the `.Random.seed` binding needs to already be there before the environment is locked. And I would strongly prefer to leave the RNG algorithm alone. [`drake`](https://github.com/ropensci/drake) is meant for a wide and diverse user base, and I think people expect Mersenne Twister to be the default. Some users might even want to set the algorithm themselves.

Comment: Actually now that I re-read your question, you already answered that: it is `.Random.seed`. I answered trying to provide a solution to the problem you have. I think you should change the question to ask about the specific problem using the information in your answer. Anyway, I edited my answer with two more thoughts that I think will help you.

Comment: Hmm... hacking into a recommended package seems too risky to implement in `drake` itself or recommend to users, but it's an [*excellent* patch idea for base R](https://www.r-project.org/bugs.html#how-to-submit-patches).

Comment: Though maybe `.Random.seed <- NULL` should be `assign(".Random.seed", NULL, envir = .GlobalEnv)`.

Comment: Good point about using `assign` - edited my answer. I think for `drake` you can use the last approach I wrote, lock and work in a new environment.

Answer (score 4):

I think `parallel:::mc.set.stream()` has the answer. Apparently, `mclapply()` tries to remove `.Random.seed` from the global environment by default. Since the default RNG algorithm is Mersenne Twister, we dive into the `else` block below.

```
> parallel:::mc.set.stream
function () 
{
    if (RNGkind()[1L] == "L'Ecuyer-CMRG") {
        assign(".Random.seed", get("LEcuyer.seed", envir = RNGenv), 
            envir = .GlobalEnv)
    }
    else {
        if (exists(".Random.seed", envir = .GlobalEnv, inherits = FALSE)) 
            rm(".Random.seed", envir = .GlobalEnv, inherits = FALSE)
    }
}
<bytecode: 0x4709808>
<environment: namespace:parallel>
```

We can use `mc.set.seed = FALSE` to make the following code work, but this is probably not a good idea in practice.

```
set.seed(0)
lockEnvironment(globalenv())
parallel::mclapply(1:2, identity, mc.cores = 2, mc.set.seed = FALSE)
```

I wonder if there is a way to lock the environment while still allowing us to remove `.Random.seed`.